# How to list data base rows twice in the same query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

You basically have two options to echo the rows in the HTML page using PHP:

Using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

Using mysqli:

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

So when you give $row the data of the first row, the pointer moves to the next row of the query. If you are going to need that same list of data in other part of the page, what is the proper thing to do?

1. Return the pointer to the first row (**how to do it?**);
2. Recall the query (and spend more time and resources);
3. Create a array with the data (**how to do it?**);

Comment: simply create `global array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use an array for this.. If nothing else, you will keep high readability of your code at least.

Comment: Do you have a code example on how to pass $row objects to array variables to show me, please? :-)

Comment: @EASI you can create a global array before the while loop `global $myarray = array();` then in the loop you will just pass your data to the array the way you want. It's all up to you, I usually use 2D arrays and pass the values like this: `$myarray[row['ID']] = array (row['firstname'], row['lastname']);`. Then you can access these data easily with the ID.... for example firstname of a person with ID 15 in the database will be in `$myarray[15][0];`